# How to perform equal_range on one key and lower_bound on the second key of a composite keyed boost multi-index container?

Tags: c++, boost-multi-index

Let say I have a class to hold the sensor measurements, and I created a boost multi-index container with composite key of time and id of each measurement:

```
namespace {
    struct ValueUpdateMsg {
        double value;
        uint64_t time;
        int id;
    };

    struct time_id {
    };
    struct id_time {
    };

    using value_set_t = bmi::multi_index_container<
            ValueUpdateMsg,
            bmi::indexed_by<
                    bmi::ordered_unique<
                            bmi::tag<struct id_time>,
                            bmi::composite_key<ValueUpdateMsg,
                                    bmi::member<ValueUpdateMsg, decltype(ValueUpdateMsg::id), &ValueUpdateMsg::id>,
                                    bmi::member<ValueUpdateMsg, uint64_t, &ValueUpdateMsg::time>

                            >
                    >,
                    bmi::ordered_unique<
                            bmi::tag<struct time_id>,
                            bmi::composite_key<ValueUpdateMsg,
                                    bmi::member<ValueUpdateMsg, uint64_t, &ValueUpdateMsg::time>,
                                    bmi::member<ValueUpdateMsg, decltype(ValueUpdateMsg::id), &ValueUpdateMsg::id>
                            >
                    >
            >
    >;
}


value_set_t container;

container.insert(ValueUpdateMsg{1, 0, 1.0});
container.insert(ValueUpdateMsg{1, 1, 2.0});
container.insert(ValueUpdateMsg{3, 0, 3.0});
container.insert(ValueUpdateMsg{3, 2, 4.0});
container.insert(ValueUpdateMsg{5, 0, 5.0});
container.insert(ValueUpdateMsg{5, 1, 6.0});
```

I would like to find the  node whose `id=2` and the update time less that to equal to 4. How can I do that in the boost-multi-index container?

I can perform the following:

```
auto id2_range = boost::make_iterator_range(container.get<id_time>().equal_range(std::make_tuple(2)));
```

To get a range of values whose `id == 2`
and perform a linear( or binary) search to find the node whose time matches the query. Is there is a better way of doing it in boost multi-index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
auto id2_range = boost::make_iterator_range(
  container.get<id_time>().lower_bound(2),
  container.get<id_time>().upper_bound(std::make_tuple(2,4))
);
```